# Master Page stuck on Seattle in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, master-page, 2016

I've been working on creating a custom master page for a customer and it is working successfully on my dev server. However when I try to added it to the customer's server and change master pages it always appears as Seattle.

Both the sites are Team Site templates with publishing features enabled on the Site Collection and Site level.

It appears as if the customers site is Stuck in Seattle, when I try changing it to the OOTB Oslo page it still remains as Seattle. I think there is an issue with their site.

Has anyone heard of this issue before, if so how do I fix it so it will use the custom master page?

Note: Yes I have upload the custom Master page correctly and I can see it on `_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx`

Update:
Change Site Master Page

[image]

After Changes

[image]

Comment: what's the template type (Publishing, team site ....etc) of your customer site?

Comment: if you have uploaded the master page, I think you need to go to master page gallery and edit the properties and then change the content type to master page for it to appear under the master pages dropdown, otherwise you'll just see the ootb master pages, as seattle

Comment: @M.Qassas I'm using a Team Site Template with publishing features turned on.

Comment: @TiagoDuarte The master page and all the scripts and styling have been uploaded and published and I can see the master page on `_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx`

Comment: so you can see it, you can apply it, you just don't see the branding? if that is the case, you must have the references wrong. check your browser console for 404s

Comment: @TiagoDuarte I can't even get the ootb Oslo page to load. The site always references the ootb Seattle.

Comment: I suggest you try to describe a bit better your issue, preferably with screen shots and example code. also, make sure you pick a master page for the root of your site collection, and then propagate it (if you wish to). you may be applying it to a subsite

Comment: The thing is the code is not the issue. There's an issue with the SharePoint Site always using Seattle and no other master page.

Comment: check the browser console for errors, check behaviour in different sites and site collections if possible, identify potential event receivers, etc. you can use sharepoint designer to set the master page as well

Comment: No errors when I check the console. I've tried setting oslo and the custom page using designer, but it's the same issue. When I refresh it's set to the ootb Seattle page.

Comment: The only solution I can think of at the moment is to modify the ootb Seattle page, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: post a screenshot of ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx page

Comment: @Aveenav done, I also posted the site after the changes are made.

Comment: change both the master pages, see if issue occurs on system master pages too. Also try using non-system account like Site Collection Admin account.

Comment: @Aveenav Once I set both the Oslo it changed and now I'm able to use my custom master page. This is a really weird bug I hope it doesn't show up again.

Comment: i think your home page was probably set to a non-publishing page (since it was a team site), that's why you couldn't see your master page applied. Look up System Master Page vs. Site Master page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what type of page you are using in the production. If it's Web part pages, for example, then you need to apply "System Master Page" instead of "Site Master Page":

[image]